# Types in function as children from component props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is there any way to get proper typings in such case?

```
<Resource data={{ foo: 1 }}>{data => data.foo}</Resource>;
                                            ^
                                     should be number
```

I've started with simple example without React and it was quite easy:

```
type IResult<P> = { [key in keyof P]: P[key] };
function foo<P>(
  c: (data: IResult<P>) => any,
  props: { data: P }
) {
  c(props.data);
}

foo(data => data.foo, { // `data.foo` is number
  data: { foo: 1 },
});
```

But when I tried to use similar implementation with React I had no luck :/

```
type IResult<P> = { [key in keyof P]: P[key] };

interface IRProps<T = any> {
  data: T;
  children(data: IResult<T>): React.ReactNode;
}

class Resource extends React.Component<IRProps> {
  render() {
    return this.props.children(this.props.data);
  }
}
```

All I can get is `(parameter) data: {}` or `(parameter) data: any`.

I'm using Typescript `v2.6.1` and React `16.2` with most recent typings.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What is your input, what do you expect to get outputted?

Comment: My problem is not about values but typings. For example

`<Resource data={{foo: "bar"}}>{data => data.foo * 2}</Resource>`

`data.foo * 2` should show TypeScript error while you can't mutiply strings.

Answer (score 0):

JSX and Generics are a bit tuff together, so we have to play a 'make typescript eat this' game:

[image]